# Celery and Rabbitmq: How to get an external worker to consume tasks from a queue

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have 2 servers A (producer) & B (Consumer).

Server A has a celery_beat task that runs every 30 seconds.

Server A is using Rabbitmq 3.5.7 and celery 4.1.0.

Server B is using celery 4.1.0

Server A can send jobs to the `tasks` queue however Server B's celery_worker does not pick them up. It returns the follwoing warning and deletes all jobs.

When running the tasks from either servers shell, they work fine I think the issue is with my celery worker config.

This is the error I am getting from server B's celery_worker.logs

```
[2018-04-08 10:07:01,083: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: '{"user": "Lewis", "status": "submitted", "start": "21-10-2017T21:08:04Z+00:00", "end": "21-10-2017T21:08:04Z+00:00", "profile_data": {"delivery_method": "ftp", "transcode_settings": "test", "delivery_settings": {"test": "test"}, "name": "Amazon", "contact_details": "test"}, "id": 78, "video_data": {"segment_data": {"segment_data": {"segment_4": {"end": "00:00:05:00", "start": "00:00:00:00"}, "segment_3": {"end": "00:00:05:00", "start": "00:15:00:00"}, "segment_1": {"end": "00:00:05:00", "start": "00:10:00:00"}, "segment_2": {"end": "00:00:05:00", "start": "00:05:00:00"}}}, "material_id": "LB000002", "total_duration": "00:00:20:00", "audio_tracks": {"en": [1, 2]}, "resolution": "SD169", "number_of_segments": 4}}' (720b)
{content_type:None content_encoding:None
  delivery_info:{'redelivered': False, 'routing_key': 'tasks', 'consumer_tag': 'None8', 'exchange': '', 'delivery_tag': 46} headers={}}
```

I have gone through both Celery & Rabbitmq's docs and I am stumped any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Here are the `settings.py` and `systemd` daemons.

Server A settings.py

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    Queue('tasks', Exchange('tasks', routing_key='tasks'))
}
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'task.tasks.schedule_task': {
        'queue': 'tasks',
        'routing_key': 'tasks',
    },
}
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'get_node_status': {
        'task': 'node_management.tasks.get_node_status',
        'schedule': 15,
    },
    'schedule_task': {
        'task': 'task.tasks.schedule_task',
        'schedule': 30,
    }
}
```

Server A task_scheduler.service

```
[Unit]
Description=celery_beat
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=fork
User=ubuntu
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/mediahub_core/bin/celery beat -A mediahub_core --loglevel=debug --logfile=/var/log/mediahub_core/celery_beat.log
StandardOutput=null
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStartSec=10
TimeoutStopSec=600
SendSIGKILL=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Server A celery_worker.service

```
[Unit]
Description=celery_worker
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=fork
User=ubuntu
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/mediahub_core/bin/celery -A mediahub_core worker --loglevel=info --logfile=/var/log/mediahub_core/celery_worker.log
StandardOutput=null
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStartSec=10
TimeoutStopSec=600
SendSIGKILL=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Server B settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://node:transcode@192.168.10.191'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    Queue('tasks', Exchange('tasks', routing_key='tasks'))
}
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'task.tasks.process_task': {
        'queue': 'tasks',
        'routing_key': 'tasks',
    },
}
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'schedule_task': {
        'task': 'transcode.tasks.process_task',
        'schedule': 10,
    },
}
```

Server B celery_worker.service

```
[Unit]
Description=celery_worker
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=fork
User=ubuntu
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/mediahub_node/bin/celery -A mediahub_node worker -Q tasks --loglevel=debug --logfile=/var/log/mediahub_node/celery_worker.log
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStartSec=10
TimeoutStopSec=600
SendSIGKILL=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Ok, so your producer is `mediahub_core` and your consumer is `mediahub_node`. Are you sure the dotted path of your inserted task can be found within consumer?

Comment: It would help if you could paste the folder structure of your `mediahub_node` and `mediahub_core` projects.